# Can I block my ID when making a FaceTime Call?

Tags: facetime

Is there a way to initiate a FaceTime call but block my identity from the person I'm making the call to? Reason: my daughter has lost her privilege to use FaceTime, but I looked at her Apple account a few minutes ago and it said that her iPhone was using FaceTime at the moment. I want to find out if she is, in fact, breaking the rules. Thank you.

Comment: `Settings > General > Restrictions` might be your friend.

Comment: > but I looked at her Apple account a few minutes ago and it said that her iPhone was using FaceTime at the moment
What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only set your Caller ID to one of the email addresses associated with your Apple ID, accessible through Settings → FaceTime.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I just received a FaceTime call from "unknown". 8/18/16

Answer (score -1):

If you mean that you would be connected to the call silently or that it would be recorded, you could try to find an app that does that… but remember, you have to get consent to record the calls or you can fined or imprisoned for invasion of privacy.

[description of invasion of privacy ]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqFxY.jpg)